# str_length is producing an error when attempting to use it for twitter data

Tags: r

I am trying to use str_length(text) to find out the length of each of the tweets I have downloaded, and it's not working. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. I keep getting the message "Error in stri_length(string) : argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)"

Is it a problem with the package stringr that I installed? Or am I doing something wrong with the str_length format?

Here's what I've done:

```
> attach(lgData2)
The following objects are masked from lgData2 (pos = 3):

    created, favoriteCount, favorited, id, isRetweet, latitude,
    longitude, replyToSID, replyToSN, replyToUID, retweetCount,
    retweeted, screenName, statusSource, text, truncated

> str_length(text)
Error in stri_length(string) : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
> str_length("text")
[1] 4
> stri_length(text)
Error in stri_length(text) : 
  argument `str` should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)
```

Comment: if you just say >text what value does it say?

Comment: Don't use `attach()`, just do `detach(lgData2); str_length(lgData2$text)` and that should work

Comment: The noticeable up-tick, of late, in questions using `attach` has to be either folks working off of resurfaced old tutorials or converts from other stats languages who are used to the horrible idioms in them.